# edit Value in Collection - variable Function ...(?)

Tags: vba, class, collections, vb6

i need your help. I want to change a class value within a collection, change “variable”.

```
cAdmin = xy
cCheckDate=yz
cPruefState= abc
colSomeName.add Classname, key1
```

I save this into a collection (colSomeName). On form, on a event is raised searched the key in the collection is and the current value is changed.

In a class I set values (for example)

```
Sub CheckOut()
.. 
editInCollection colSomeName, „StackOver“
. . . 



Public Function editInCollection( _
                    ByRef col As Collection, _
                    ByRef Elem As String) As Boolean

    On Error GoTo Ende  
    If IsEmpty(col(Elem)) Then
        MsgBox " This Element: " & col(Elem) & „ not exits!", _
                vbCritical = vbOKOnly, "s o r r y "
    Exit Function
    End If`enter code here`
    IsInCollection = (Err.Number = 0)
        '
        col(Elem).cAdmin =Environ("username") 
        col(Elem).cCheckDate = Date 
        col(Elem).cPruefState= True
        ' 
    Exit Function

    Ende:  
        IsInCollection = False
    End Function
```

It works perfect. 
But i would like to use the funkion for different classes / collection.
Is this **possiple**? **My idear is** like this

```
Public Function editInCollection( _
                ByRef col As Collection, _
                ByRef Elem As String, clsValue as Variant(?), newValue as variant) As Boolean

Dim as ….
For each xAll in col(Elem)
        If xAll = clsValue then
       clsVlaue = newValue
        end if
   exit for
next
end function
```

but i doesn’t work.  How can I realize this

Comment: Can you [edit] your example (the top snippet) with something a bit more concrete? IMO it's hard to understand what you're trying to do and why.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CallByName` to access an object's property using the name of the property:

clsTest: a very simple class for testing purposes...

```
Option Explicit
Public TestProperty As String
```

Example code:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim o As New clsTest, col As New Collection

    o.TestProperty = "hello"

    col.Add o, "key1"

    Debug.Print "Before", o.TestProperty '>>> hello

    'Update the property named "TestProperty" to "I was updated"
    Debug.Print "updated?", EditInCollection(col, "key1", _
                            "TestProperty", "I was updated") '>>> true

    Debug.Print "After", o.TestProperty  '>>> I was updated

End Sub



Function EditInCollection(col, key, propName, newValue)

    Dim o As Object, rv As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    Set o = col(key)   'is there an object with this key?
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not o Is Nothing Then
        'Object was found in the collection: update 
        '  the property in "propName" to "newValue"
        CallByName o, propName, VbLet, newValue
        rv = True
    End If

    EditInCollection = rv 'return success or failure
End Function
```

If you wanted to update multiple properties then you could adapt the function to accept an array of property names and an array of new values as the third and fourth parameters.

Comment: Hallo Tim - it works so great! You make me so happy - thank you very much!